# pass task instance variables as op_args

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-webserver

I want to use my `function_two` multiple times with different values for the `my_list` vairable.

I know I can use returned variables from one function into another using the xcom pull function. However, if I pull, I have to do it from within the python callable (for example in `function_two` in this case). This means that I can only use the function with one `my_list` value.

```
def function_one(**kwargs):
   return my_list

def function_two(**kwargs):
   my_list = task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='one')
   # manipulating the list


get_one = PythonOperator(
        task_id='one',
        python_callable=get_one
)

get_two = PythonOperator(
        task_id='two',
        python_callable=get_two
)

get_three = PythonOperator(
        task_id='three',
        python_callable=get_two
        op_args=.....

)
```

Instead, I want to re-use `function_two` with different values of `my_list` as parameters where I will be returning the lists from different other python callables.

Is there any way to pass specific `task_instance` op_args in the PythonOperators such that I can call the same python callable in different operators but with different values for the my_list as the parameter?

For example, if I am returning another list here:

```
def new_function(**kwargs):
   return new_list
```

I want to create a new PythonOperator that calls the same `function_two` with this `new_list` as the parameter.

Comment: Would you give a specific example as to what the input and output will be of each operator?